# Export Model to DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want to convert my Model data to `DataSet` or `DataTable` (to export in excel format)

```
db.EMPs.ToList()
```

`db` is `DataContext` , `EMPs` is `dataclass` .

How to export this list to `DataTable`, I can export rows to excel but how to access column name from header (column name should not be added manually in `DataTable`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ToDataTable` extension method but you need to install [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) first. To install `MoreLINQ`, run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

> PM> Install-Package morelinq

Then add the following line to your `using` directives:

```
using MoreLinq;
```

And finally you can use `ToDataTable` extension method:

```
DataTable s = db.EMPs.ToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

To quickly create a file that can be read in Excel you could map the contents to a comma-separated value list using LINQ and then save the array to a file stream.

```
var records = db.EMP
                .ToList()
                .Select(record => $"\"{record.stringField}\",{record.numberField}")
                .ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines("file.csv", records);
```

Comment: What does stringField and numberField means here ?

Comment: It shows <br>  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: It was to indicate fields in your table that are strings or numbers. strings can be enclosed in quotes to easier reading by Excel.

Comment: Ah! The exception is because you cannot pass string formatting to Entity Framework. I've updated the code to retrieve the data and then convert it to a string array.

Answer (score 0):

Using `MoreLinq` is the best way to convert a class to `DataTable` as already answered by S.Akbari
Below is another way I found to accomplish this by using `System.Reflection`

```
List<EMP> list= db.EMPs.ToList();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();       
PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(EMP).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
{
    //Setting column names as Property names
    dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
}

foreach (EMP e in list)
{
    var values = new object[Props.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
    {
        //inserting property values to datatable rows
        values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(e, null);
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(values);
}
```