# How to convert list Object to DataTable object

Tags: c#, list, datatable

> cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic.List
>   to System.Data.DataTable

```
List<string> selectedCustomer = new List<string>();
selectedCustomer.Add(CustomerID);
selectedCustomer.Add(FirstName);
selectedCustomer.Add(LastName);

DataTable dt = selectedCustomer;
```

How can this error message above be resolved?

Comment: Use `MoreLinq` like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42550827/2946329

Answer (score 0):

```
static DataTable GetTable()
{
    // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    // Here we add five DataRows.
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
    return table;
}
```

HEPSİ ALINTIDIR!

Comment: Please answer questions in English.